# Inject variable into html via Gulp Task

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I'm using Gulp and a number of plugins to template my HTML and minify my HTML i.e.  "gulp-file-include", "gulp-inject", "gulp-minify-html" none seem to offer a way of injecting a constant at build time i.e something like this:

.pipe('*.html', $.gulpVar({urlpath: 'www.myurl.com'})))

then in my HTML a reference to the variable

Contact Us

The closest I can find to something similar is gulp-ng-constant although this injects it into the JS and uses Angular, but I'm not using Angular and wish to inject it into the HTML. Is there a gulp plugin that has that feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use gulp-replace

```
gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src('template.html')
    .pipe(replace(/$$myvar$$/g, 'release'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/file.txt'));
});
```

above task is replacing `$$myvar$$` by `release` in `template.html`

Comment: Yes that would do the job, also I see gulp-preprocess could be used to do what I need but I go with gulp-replace for now