# How to execute a gulp task even if the file is unchanged

Tags: javascript, gulp

**EDIT: Additional addition of code for task execution**

I have a question I can't answer. I need gulp to execute a stain even if the file is unchanged. Currently only when I change my source file it recreates the new destination file. But I would like it to create it even if it hasn't changed. Thank's you in advance :)

Library external :  "gulp-inject-string": "^1.1.2",

```
    // Add timestamp in cache PWA
    function pwa_cache() {
      return src(`${paths.pwa}/serviceworker.tmp.js`)
        .pipe(inject.prepend('const CACHE_VERSION = "pwa-v-'+ new Date().getTime() +'"; \n'))
        .pipe(rename('serviceworker.js'))
        .pipe(dest(`${paths.js}/pwa/`,{overwrite:true}))
    }
    // Generate all assets
const generateAssets = parallel(
  styles,
  scripts,
  pwa_cache,
  imgCompression
)
exports.default = series(generateAssets)
exports["generate-assets"] = generateAssets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I proceeded differently, if it can help someone, it's the only way I found and I don't have time to find another solution.
Instead of adding I rather assign the variable in my file and then I change its value, and I no longer work on a template file but directly on the original file.
Post and link that helped me find the answer: https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2015/07/13/gulp-rewrite-source-files-instead-of-creating-new-files/, [How to inject variable value into JS file from GULP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164019/how-to-inject-variable-value-into-js-file-from-gulp), [Inject variable into html via Gulp Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703688/inject-variable-into-html-via-gulp-task)

**gulp file :**

```
// Add timestamp in cache PWA
function pwa_cache() {
    return src(`${paths.js}/pwa/serviceworker.js`, {base: './'})
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(replace(new RegExp('django-pwa-v-\\d*', 's'), 'django-pwa-v-'+ new Date().getTime()))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(dest('./'))

}
```

**js file :**

```
// Cache version don't touch string assigned to the variable /
CACHE_VERSION = "django-pwa-v-1580491632502";
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe running this task within a `gulp.watch()` ? If so, you'd need to stop the watch task and re-run it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, not the one if executed in a parallel task.